# WAMP stack for serving public pages?

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, mysql, wamp

I have XAMPP, and think it is quite cool, although it is advised to use it for serving public pages.

What is a WAMP stack which is suited to serving public pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAMPP is good, the best as far as I know in comparison to all the other WAMP stacks available, earlier I used to use [WAMP server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) but I quickly switched to XAMPP as it had an addon for Tomcat as well. But personally I wouldn't use it for a production environment as the defaults are not secure enough, its okay if its just a personal site.You would also be interested in [this link](http://robsnotebook.com/xampp-security-hardening), it shows you how to further secure your XAMPP server

If u want to use a WAMP stack for serving public pages, I would advise you to go with XAMPP.

*Additional reading: [Configuring a WAMP stack for production](http://blog.whyley.com/2008/12/17/configuring-a-wamp-stack-for-production/)*